# Why does this promise silently fail?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

`db.collection.findOne` is an async operation (MongoDB, but that doesn't really matter here), which is why I'm wrapping it in a promise here.

```
var letsDoSomething = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    db.collection('stackoverflow').findOne({question: true}, function(err, question){
        resolve(question); // let's pretend we found a question here, and it is now resolving
    })
})

letsDoSomething.then(function(myData){ // it resolves
    console.log('foo', bar); // since 'bar' is undefined, this should fail – why doesn't it? No error messages, it goes completely silent
});
```

Why doesn't the debugger throw an error when I try to log `bar`, which simply doesn't exist? It just goes *poof* silent, not a word.

Expected result (in my mind):

```
console.log('foo', bar);
ReferenceError: bar is not defined
```

What am I missing?

*Environment:*

```
node -v
v0.12.4
```

Comment: perhaps "pretend we found a question here" isn't enough to actually resolve the Promise

Comment: No, it will resolve the promise!

Comment: Use io.js and not nodejs and use the `process.on("unhandledRejection"` event, or use a library that's drop-in like Bluebird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not swallowing that error, but if a `then` or `catch` handler results in an error, then the current promise will be rejected with that error.

In your case, `ReferenceError` is thrown, but it rejects the promise. You can see the actual error being propagated, by attaching a `catch` handler, like this

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve(true);
  })
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result, bar);
  })
  .catch(function (er) {
    console.error('Inside Catch', er);
  });
```

Now you will see

```
Inside Catch [ReferenceError: bar is not defined]
```

---

Further Reading:

1. [Why cannot I throw inside a Promise.catch handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30715635/1903116)