# Result of a promise inside of forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to rewrite the code of one my project with the promise (Q).
I don't know how to take the result of a chain of promises inside a foreach loop:

```
var resProducts = [];
products.forEach(currProduct) {
     Stock.saveNewStock(currProduct)
        .then(function(res1) {
            Product.saveNewProduct(currProduct)
               .then(function(res2) {
                  resProducts.push(res2);
                  Product.addStockToProduct(res1,res2)
               })
         })
         .catch(function(err) {
             console.log(err)
         })
});
console.log(resProducts);
```

I see that every time the log stamps an empty array, so how I can resolve it?

Comment: As a side note: javascript is synchronous and your function call to print the array value is outside the async block which makes it run almost instantly. Could be worth to reflect upon! :)

Answer (score 7):

You should always [return all promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37084467/918910), and you're forgetting to in several places here.

If you can use => arrow functions, then these implicitly return, which avoids forgetting.

Instead of `forEach` which ignores return values, use `map` and return results into an array. This does the work in parallel as well:

```
Promise.all(products.map(product => Stock.saveNewStock(product)
  .then(res1 => Product.saveNewProduct(product)
    .then(res2 => Product.addStockToProduct(res1, res2)
      .then(() => res2))))
.then(resProducts => console.log(resProducts))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

The nesting here is intentional, to access `res1` and `res2` together.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
// Define iterator function
function doThingsWithProducts(productsLeft, resProducts) {
    if (productsLeft.length === 0) { return resProducts }
    else {
        var currProduct = productsLeft.shift(), res1, res2;
        return Stock.saveNewStock(currProduct)
        .then(function(res) {
            res1 = res;
            return Product.saveNewProduct(currProduct)
        })
        .then(function(res) {
            res2 = res;
            resProducts.push(res2);
            return Product.addStockToProduct(res1, res2)
        })
        .then(function() {
            return doThingsWithProducts(productsLeft, resProducts)
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
}

// resProducts is available in the result of the function
doThingsWithProducts(products, [])
.then(function(resProducts) {
    console.log(resProducts);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is that you need?

```
var defer = $q.defer();
            var promises = [];
            var resProducts = [];
            var errorCallback = function (e) {

              defer.reject();
            };

           products.forEach(currProduct) {

                promises.push(function () {
                    Stock.saveNewStock(currProduct)
                        .then(function(res1) {
                            return Product.saveNewProduct(currProduct)
                        .then(function(res2) {
                            resProducts.push(res2);
                            Product.addStockToProduct(res1,res2)
                   })
             })
             .catch(function(err) {
                 console.log(err)
             })
                }


                );
              }

            });
            return $q.all(promises);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in combination with [Q.all()](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination)

```
var resProducts = [];

Q.all(products.map(function (currProduct) {
        // Return promise that Q.all() can resolve.
        return Stock.saveNewStock(currProduct)
            .then(function (res1) {
                // Make sure you always return promises when they
                // are in a chain so  the chain will work correctly.
                return Product.saveNewProduct(currProduct)
                    .then(function (res2) {
                        resProducts.push(res2);
                        return Product.addStockToProduct(res1, res2)
                    })
            })
    }))
    .then(function (products) {
        // Products here is the array of resolved promises.

        // and here your array will be full.
        console.log(resProducts);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    });
```