# Firebase (Angular) Promises with Loops in Loops

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, firebase-realtime-database

How do you execute a function only after all the promises are resolved where you have to wait for async calls in loops within loops?

The code is simplified to the minimum

```
$scope.book = function(input) {

  //Get the cart items from DB
  ref.child('/cart/' + userId).once('value').then(function(cartSnap) {

    //Loop through the cart items
    cartSnap.forEach(function(cartItemSnap) {

      var itemId = cartItemSnap.key();

      //Get the inventory items from DB that are in the cart
      ref.child('/inventory/' + itemId).once('value').then(function(inventoryItem) {

        //Loop through booking IDs of inventoryItem
        inventoryItem.child('rentals').forEach(function(rentalSnap) {

          var rentalId = rentalSnap.key();

          //Get bookings from rental/active
          ref.child('/rental/'+ rentalId).once('value').then(function(activeRentals) {

            checkIfBookingIsAllowed();

          });
        });
      });
    });

    //Once everything was checked
    bookRental();
  });
};
```

To improve speed all the requests can be made in parallel but the final function bookRental() can only be called when everything is resolved.

Thanks for your help.

EDITED:
Another try that failed. The Promise.all('collector') gets fired before all the promises are resolved. So 'done' shows up before all the 'checks' in the console.

```
$scope.book = function(input) {

  //Get the cart items from DB
  ref.child('/cart/' + userId).once('value').then(function(cartSnap) {

    //Promise collector
    var collector = [];

    //Loop through the cart items
    cartSnap.forEach(function(cartItemSnap) {

      var itemId = cartItemSnap.key();

      //Get the inventory items from DB that are in the cart
      var promise1 = ref.child('/inventory/' + itemId).once('value').then(function(inventoryItem) {

        //Loop through booking IDs of inventoryItem
        inventoryItem.child('rentals').forEach(function(rentalSnap) {

          var rentalId = rentalSnap.key();

          //Get bookings from rental/active
          var promise2 = ref.child('/rental/'+ rentalId).once('value').then(function(activeRentals) {

            console.log('check');
            collector.push(promise2);

          });
        });

        collector.push(promise1);
      });
    });

    //Once everything was checked
    Promise.all(collector).then(function() {
      console.log('Done');
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: what does `checkIfBookingIsAllowed` do? could you please add this code?

Comment: It checks the date overlap and the quantity of an item. It's not really relevant for my problem. You could simply exchange this line with a console.log('check');

Comment: Use `Promise.all()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the help. I tried, check my new code. What am I missing?

Comment: You're loading data asynchronously, so need to ensure that your promises "bubble up". It's a bit tricky to write an answer without testing. Any chance you could reproduce the problem in a jsbin, so that I can make that work?

Comment: here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbrdrV?editors=1111).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're collecting the promises too late. Collect them *now*, not later. Code inside `.then`s runs later.

Here's what runs immediately:

1. Both nested for-loops run to completion, minus all code inside `.then`s.
2. `Promise.all(collector)`.

At this point `collector` is still empty, so `Promise.all()` completes real fast.

Move the `collector.push(promise)` calls outside of the `.then`s.

#### A more functional approach:

With the above fix, your code should work, but a cleaner approach is to [return all promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37084467/918910). While `forEach` doesn't allow return values, `map` does, so this can be re-written as (simplifying):

```
Promise.all(cartSnap.map(snap => ref.child(itemUrl).once('value').then(item =>
  Promise.all(item.child('rentals').map(snap => ref.child(url).once('value'))))))
.then(allActiveRentals => console.log('Done'));
```

Comment: thank jib for this approach. firebase doesn't return an array but an object which doesn't include the map function. is there another way?

Comment: @stefan Whatever you're doing `forEach` on is an array, so that's where you can use `map` instead. Use `map` on an object like this: `Object.keys(obj).map(key => foo(obj[key]))`.

Comment: Ok this works for Objects. Now I'm simply struggling with the logic. I made a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbrdrV?editors=1111) but the first loop still finishes before the nested ones. I know why but can't figure out how to do it right.

Comment: You're still not [returning all the promises](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37084467/918910), specifically, you're missing `return Promise.all` (note that with arrow functions, the return is implicit when brackets are not used, i.e. `x => 2*x` has an implicit return, like `x => { return 2*x; }`. Also still not sure what kind of thing `cartSnap` is, you're not calling `.key()` anymore whatever that is, so is the `itemId` correct?

Comment: Ok, after I returned all the promises it seems to work! thanks. Yes itemId is already the key. I didn't try it with the arrow function. but here's the updated version: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jAgKAj?editors=1111)