# Firestore Loops with Promises

Tags: javascript, firebase, loops, promise, google-cloud-functions

I cannot figure out what is wrong with how I'm implementing promises inside loops in a Firebase function. I get this error when running this function as a Firebase Scheduled function: "TypeError: undefined is not a function" specifying line 202 in my index.js (below). The function is not running to completion (all of the `.then`s are not completing). I have two other concerns:

1. That I'm not using Promise.all correctly and not returning promises in the proper places.
2. I get this error in my Firebase logs: "Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string." when trying to get the document within the path in section 2 of the code below. The path is correct and is indeed strings as I have verified by inspecting the reference object.

   ```
     checkForTweetsToDelete: function(db) {

       ///////
       // 1. Get first collction - streamers
       let streamersRef = db.collection('streamers');
       let streamersQuery = streamersRef.get()
         .then(streamersSnap => {

           var promises = [];

           ///////
           // 2. Get settings for each streamer - Here is where I get a "Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string."
           streamersSnap.forEach(streamerDoc => {

             let tweetSettingsRef = db.collection('streamers').doc((streamerDoc.id.toString())).collection('TweetSettings').doc('Settings');
             let settingsDoc = tweetSettingsRef.get()
               .then(doc => {

                   ///////
                   // 3. Get all 'no' Tweets for this streamer
                   let tweetsRef = db.collection('streamers').doc(doc.data().twitchId).collection('TwitterPosts');
                   let tweetsQuery = tweetsRef.where('deleted', '==', 'no').get()
                     .then(tweetsSnap => {

                       var tweetPromises = [];

                       tweetsSnap.forEach(tweetDoc => {

                         /////////////
                         // 4. Delete Tweet
                         const client = new Twitter({
                           subdomain: "api", // "api" is the default (change for other subdomains)
                           version: "1.1", // version "1.1" is the default (change for other subdomains)
                           consumer_key: APP_KEY, // from Twitter.
                           consumer_secret: APP_SECRET, // from Twitter.
                           access_token_key: USER_TOKEN, // from your User (oauth_token)
                           access_token_secret: SECRET // from your User (oauth_token_secret)
                         });

                         const user = client.post('statuses/destroy', {
                           id: tweetDoc.id,
                           trim_user: 1
                         })
                         .then(twitterResponse => {

                           ///////
                           // 5. Write to DB that this has been deleted.
                           let tweetRef = tweetsRef.doc(tweetDoc.id.toString());
                           let updatedDoc = tweetRef.set({
                             deleted : 'yes'
                           }, {merge: true}).then(() => {
                             return;
                           });

                           return Promise.all([updatedDoc]);
                           // 5
                           ///////

                         });
                         // 4
                         /////////////

                         tweetPromises.push(user);

                       });

                       return Promise.all(tweetPromises);
                     });

                     return Promise.all([tweetsQuery]);
                     // 3
                     ///////

               });

               promises.push(settingsDoc);
           });

           return Promise.all(promises);
           // 2
           ///////
         });

       return Promise.all([streamersQuery]);
       // 1
       ///////
     }
   ```

And my index.js

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun((context) => {
            console.log('This will run every 1 minutes!');

            var scheduled = require('./scheduledFunctions');
            if (admin.apps.length === 0 ) { admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase); }
            var db = admin.firestore();

            //scheduled.checkForTweetsToDelete(db);
            //return scheduled.checkForTweetsToDelete(db);
            return Promise.all( scheduled.checkForTweetsToDelete(db) ).then(function() { // Line 202
                console.log('Finished all promises!');
            });
        });
```

I removed most of the logic inside the `.then`s as well as the `catch`s for readability.

EDIT:

This question was helpful in understanding how this all should work: [Firebase (Angular) Promises with Loops in Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151939/firebase-angular-promises-with-loops-in-loops) and after studying it I think I'm doing it just as explained, but still unsuccessful.

Comment: Have you considered using async/await to flatten your code structure? Might also solve your problem, but the example is a bit difficult to understand rn

Comment: After struggling with this for two days I'm considering it, yes. Basically I've got a .then, a for loop, a .then, a for loop.

Comment: Basically I've got a .then -> for loop -> .then -> for loop -> .then. The deepest for loop needs to finish its .then s before iterating to the next value in the parent for loop.

Comment: Can't see why you might be getting that particular error, however once it is solved, you will need to address ...

 return Promise.all( scheduled.checkForTweetsToDelete(db) ).then(...)
 
... in which `scheduled.checkForTweetsToDelete(db)` returns Promise, not Array, therefore `Promise.all()` is inappropriate.

Instead, simplify to ...
 
 return scheduled.checkForTweetsToDelete(db).then(...);

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I did that and it fixed that error. I also solved the other problem. Was due to incorrect path on my part.

Comment: Excellent. Well worked out. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was calling the incorrect path elsewhere in my code. I was getting a value from the database then using it to call another reference path but that value was undefined. After fixing that I was able to fix the other promise error by following Roamer-1888's advice.