# Optimising a nested promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

How can I optimise the following (i.e. avoid nested promises)? It works but seems like I'm going to continue nesting promises

The code first authenticates and returns a service, then it feeds that service into a function that calls the api asynchronously to gets items, then I'll do something with the items after, probably calling another function containing an async call:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    auth.authenticate(resolve);
}).then(function(service) {
    console.log('service', service);
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        lineItems.getLineItems(service, resolve, reject);
    }).then(function(items) {
        console.log('returned line items');
        console.log(items);
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log('error!', err);
    });
});
```

Comment: This code is error-prone, because you don't [return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081508/resolving-an-array-of-promises-from-within-a-parent-promise/37084467#37084467) the second promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the new promise from `then`:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    auth.authenticate(resolve);
}).then(function(service) {
    console.log('service', service);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        lineItems.getLineItems(service, resolve, reject);
    });
}).then(function(items) {
    console.log('returned line items');
    console.log(items);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log('error!', err);
});
```

Also, if you can adjust `lineItems.getLineItems` to return a promise, it looks more concise:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    auth.authenticate(resolve);
}).then(function(service) {
    console.log('service', service);
    return lineItems.getLineItems(service);
}).then(function(items) {
    console.log('returned line items');
    console.log(items);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log('error!', err);
});
```

Comment: So is it good practice to be creating promises in this fashion and passing through resolve/reject to functions? Or is it better for the function that I'm calling to be a promise in the first place?

Comment: If `lineItems.getLineItems` is designed by you, IMO this is redundant to pass `resolve` and `reject` there. You'd better make it to take only `service` as an argument and return a promise. So you can just `return lineItems.getLineItems(service);` instead of `return new Promise(function(resolve, ...`

Comment: If you can add that to your answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of issues primarily on the way functions are defined. This actually comes from non-standard signatures of async functions defined in code.

If `auth.authenticate` and `lineItems.getLineItems` are written by you, update these functions to return a proper Promise. Then the composition would be:

```
auth.authenticate()
    .then((service) => lineItems.getLineItems(service))
    .then((items)   => console.info('Items:',items))
    .catch((err)    => console.error(err));
```

If `auth.authenticate` and/or `lineItems.getLineItems` are external, and follow the standard nodejs callbak/errback style, you can wrap these function to return a promise:

```
const authenticate = Promise.promisify(auth.authenticate, {context:auth});
const getLineItems = Promise.promisify(lineItems.getLineItems,{context:lineItems});

authenticate()
    .then(getLineItems)
    .then((items)   => console.info('Items:',items))
    .catch((err)    => console.error(err));
```