# WebRTC using VueJS: Why the remote video is not playing?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, webrtc, es6-promise

I am making a sample application where there will be two video elements and a button "Call". The first video element (`#localVideo`) will show the output of the local media stream. When i press the call button the remote video element will play the remote media stream. I have made the same application in raw JavaScript, which is working fine.

In VueJS, i am making a WebRTC component to get the user media and set the stream to the local video element. When users press the call button, i am creating both of the `RTCPeerConnection` objects, sending the offer, setting local description, sending answer and all.

here is the template of the component -

```
<template>
  <div class="webRTC">
    <video id = "localVideo" playsinline autoplay muted></video>
    <button id = "call" v-on:click='call'> Call </button>
    <video id = "remoteVideo" playsinline autoplay controls></video>
  </div>
</template>

<script src="./webRTC.js"></script>
```

And here is the script for the component -

```
export default {
  name: 'webRTC',
  sockets: {
    connect: function () {
      console.log('Socket IO connected!')
    },

    TestConnection: function () {
      console.log('Test connection successful!')
    }
  },

  data: function () {
    return {
      localStream: null,
      remoteStream: null,
      pc1: null,
      pc2: null
    }
  },

  methods: {
    call: function () {
      this.pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection()
      this.pc1.addEventListener('icecandidate', e => this.addIceCandidate(this.pc1, e))

      this.pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection()
      this.pc2.addEventListener('icecandidate', e => this.addIceCandidate(this.pc2, e))
      this.pc2.addEventListener('track', this.gotRemoteStrem)

      this.localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
        console.log('Adding local stream')
        this.pc1.addTrack(track, this.localStream)
      })

      this.pc1.createOffer({ offerToReceiveAudio: 1, offerToReceiveVideo: 1 }).then(this.gotDescription)
    },

    gotRemoteStrem: function (event) {
      console.log('Got Remote stream')
      let remoteVideo = document.querySelector('#remoteVideo')
      this.remoteStream = event.streams[0]
      remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0]
    },

    gotDescription: function (description) {
      console.log('Got description 1')
      this.pc1.setLocalDescription(description)
      this.pc2.setRemoteDescription(description)

      this.pc2.createAnswer().then(this.gotDescription2)
    },

    gotDescription2: function (description) {
      console.log('Got description 2')
      this.pc2.setLocalDescription(description)
      this.pc1.setRemoteDescription(description)
    },

    addIceCandidate: function (pc, event) {
      this.getOtherPC(pc).addIceCandidate(event.candidate).then(this.addIceCandicateSuccess).catch(this.addIceCandicateFailure)
    },

    addIceCandicateSuccess: function () {
      console.log('Ice candidate added successfully')
    },

    addIceCandicateFailure: function () {
      console.log('Ice candidate failure')
    },

    getOtherPC: function (pc) {
      if (pc === this.pc1) {
        return this.pc2
      }

      return this.pc1
    },

    gotDevices: function (stream) {
      let localVideo = document.querySelector('#localVideo')
      this.localStream = stream
      localVideo.srcObject = stream
    },

    handleMediaError: function (error) {
      console.error('Error:' + error.name)
    }
  },

  created: function () {
    console.log('webRTC is created!')
    let prom = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true }).then(this.gotDevices).catch(this.handleMediaError)
  }
}
```

The local video is showing properly. The problem i am facing is that, when i am pressing the `Call` button, the remote video is not showing anything, rather i see a loading circle like in the screenshot. There is no console error as well.

[image]

I have debugged and saw the `srcObject` of both local and remote video and they appears to be same -
[image] 
Can anyone please tell me if i am doing something wrong? Also is there any other way to debug this?

**Note:**

The project/source code can be downloaded from here, if you want you can download and check the code. I will try to prepare a codepen - 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e7C0ojZ0jT7EXFNtCKcWpJBpKd_mWi_s

Comment: Can you please provide an example somewhere to test it

Comment: @TimurGilauri Can you please check the note at the end of the question? I have added the source code now. I will try to set up a codepen if its not okay to download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using promises without `async`/`await` requires [propagating errors manually](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Error_propagation) and checking them.

Add a `catch` e.g. here to see errors:

```
this.pc1.createOffer({offerToReceiveAudio: 1, offerToReceiveVideo: 1})
  .then(this.gotDescription)
  .catch(e => console.log(e)); // <-- here
```

...and you should see that `this` is `undefined` inside `gotDescription()`. That's because you're passing a member function as a callback to the `then` function, which ends up invoking it without a `this`. Either use `this.gotDescription.bind(this)` or (nicer) arrow functions. E.g.:

```
this.pc1.createOffer({offerToReceiveAudio: 1, offerToReceiveVideo: 1})
  .then(offer => this.gotDescription(offer)) // arrow function invoking on this
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Furthermore, unless you [return all the promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37084467/918910), they won't form a single chain to catch all errors.

All these calls return promises, which you're ignoring:

```
/* const unusedPromise1 = */ this.pc1.setLocalDescription(description)
/* const unusedPromise2 = */ this.pc2.setRemoteDescription(description)
/* const unusedPromise3 = */ this.pc2.createAnswer().then(this.gotDescription2)
```

Luckily (and perhaps confusingly), *RTCPeerConnection* automatically queues operations done on it, so this may actually work, provided there are no errors, which may get swallowed, depending on browser.

Instead, to catch errors, either do this:

```
this.pc1.setLocalDescription(description)
.then(() => this.pc2.setRemoteDescription(description))
.then(() => this.pc2.createAnswer())
.then(answer => this.gotDescription2(answer))
.catch(e => console.log(e))
```

or use the nicer `async`/`await` syntax which propagates errors correctly:

```
gotDescription: async function (description) {
  console.log('Got description 1')
  await this.pc1.setLocalDescription(description)
  await this.pc2.setRemoteDescription(description)
  await this.gotDescription2(await this.pc2.createAnswer());
}
```