# Is using async in setTimeout valid?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout, ecmascript-2017

I had a asynchronous function in Javascript and I added setTimeout to it. The code looks like this:

```js
let timer;
clearTimeout(timer);
timer =setTimeout(() => {
(async() => {
    await this._doSomething();
})();
}, 2000);
```

The purpose of setTimeout is to add 2 seconds before function will be run. It is to be sure that user stopped typing.

Should I remove async/await from this function now, since setTimeout is asynchronous anyway?

Comment: _"The code looks like that"_ Unlikely, and that's why you shouldn't remove `async` and `await`. It makes no sense in this example, but that doesn't mean it's pointless in (the) real code.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking here exactly. How is the piece of code **supposed** to work and how might removing `async` and `await` **change** that? Without a clear question that has an actual *answer* to it, you are just getting very broad and opinionated advice.

Comment: I have edited question to make it more clear what I am trying to achive.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`setTimeout` adds a delay ***before*** a function call, whereas `async`/`await` is syntactic sugar ontop of promises, a way to chain code to run ***after*** a call completes, so they're different.

setTimeout has terrible error-handling characteristics, so I recommend the following in all code:

```
let wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

and then never call `setTimeout` directly again.

Your code now becomes:

```
let foo = async () => {
  await wait(2000);
  await this._doSomething();
}
```

except `foo` waits for `doSomething` to finish. This is usually desirable, but without context it's hard to know what you want. If you meant to run `doSomething` in parallel with other code, I recommend:

```
async () => { await Promise.all([foo(), this._otherCode()]); };
```

to join and capture errors in the same place.

If you truly meant to fire and forget `_doSomething` and not wait for it, you can lose the `await`, but you should try/catch errors:

```
async () => {
  let spinoff = async () => { try { await foo(); } catch (e) { console.log(e); } };
  spinoff(); // no await!
}
```

But I don't recommend that pattern, as it's subtle and can be easy to miss.