# Console.log showing up at the end of the function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make a little Twitter bot with JavaScript and Node.JS. But, in a function, all my console.log are showing up at the end.

I've tried with async, callback and classic function but I always get the same output.

```
    getTweets: function(Twitter, callback) {
        Twitter.get(`search/tweets`, this.parameters, callback);
    },

    likeTweet: function(Twitter, tweetid, callback) {
        Twitter.post(`favorites/create`, { id:tweetid }, callback);
    },

    execute: function(Twitter) {

        let count = 0;
        let done = 0;

        this.getTweets(Twitter, (err, tweets) => {

            for (thetweet of tweets.statuses) {

                if (typeof thetweet === `undefined`) {
                    continue;
                }

                count++;

                this.likeTweet(Twitter, thetweet.id_str, (err, reponse) => {

                    if (err) {
                        switch (err.code) {
                            case 139: console.log(`Tweet ${count}:`.bold.yellow + ` Le tweet a déjà été aimé par le bot.`); break;
                            default: console.log(`Tweet ${count}:`.bold.red + ` Erreur inconnue => ${err}`); break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log(`Tweet ${count}:`.bold.green + ` Tweet aimé`);
                        done++;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Before I call **execute()**, I have a **console.log(1)**. After **execute()**, there is an another **console.log(3)**. And in **execute()**, there are **console.log()** that show a text. *(Yeah I know, there is a lot of console.log)*

I would like to have that:

> 1
>
> Tweet 1: text
>
> Tweet 2: text
>
> Tweet 3: text
>
> ...
>
> 3

But, when I run bot.js, I'm getting this:

> 1
>
> 3
>
> Tweet 15: text
>
> Tweet 15: text
>
> Tweet 15: text
>
> ...

I'm pretty sure that the problem is easy to spot but I don't know how to do. I hope I'm clear enough and I don't make to many mistakes with my message.

Comment: You use `await` and callbacks here :/ why?

Comment: In fact, I'm pretty sure that I forget to remove them. But even without `await` and `async`, the problem is still the same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512388/understanding-async-await-on-nodejs - This is a nice thread in case you want to know more about async and await usage, there are a few examples provided here which you may find useful.

Comment: Thanks, I will read this thread

Comment: @EmpireDémocratiqueduPoulpe the problem itself is really nothing to do with Promises or `async` / `await` - it's a very common [closure problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

await will work only on Promises, not on callback functions. await waits for the Promise to fulfill.

You can use any Promise library to make Twitter callback functions as promise and use await against them. I would prefer bluebird.

```
import {Promise} from 'bluebird'
import {Twitter} from 'twitter'
Promise.promisifyAll(Twitter);
```

Now you could use await and make it look like synchronous code.

```
let tweets = await Twitter.get(`search/tweets`,parameters);
```