# POST REQUEST BY NEXT JS 14

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, next.js

how to make POST REQUEST by next js 14 using axios or fetch but i prefer axios,
i try but alway show to me AxiosError: NewWorkError when try fetch show to me typeError: fetch faild

but it success with postman

i want sent request to **http://localhost:3001/CreateUser**

`
const POST = () => {

```
const PostRequest = async () => {
    try {
        const response await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/CreateUser", {
        nameOfUser: "mostafa",
        ageOfUser: 22,
        phoneNumber: 201003443454,
        EmailOfUser: "mostafa@gmail.com",
      })
   } catch(error) {
       console.log(error.message);
   }
}

return <button onClick={() => PostRequest()}>POST</button>
```

}

export default POST;
`

i research in youtube and ask chat gpt and copilot and try by my self

Comment: Using `fetch()` you would pass your plain JavaScript object to `JSON.stringify()` and set that on `body`, e.g., `fetch(url, {method:"post", body: JSON.stringify({a:1, b:2})})`. In general, plain JavaScript objects are not capable of being sent across the network via `POST`.

Comment: can you writ the code

Comment: You can use the code I posted in my comment, substituting your plain JavaScript object for `{a:1, b:2}` - as long as you are using `fetch()`.

Answer (score 0):

POST call in the Next.js page
imports Axios, a popular library for making HTTP requests, which we'll use to perform the POST request.

```js
import axios from 'axios';
```

This function will be called when the button is clicked. We mark it as async to enable the use of await inside the function for asynchronous behavior.

```js
const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/CreateUser", {
  nameOfUser: "mostafa",
  ageOfUser: 22,
  phoneNumber: 201003443454,
  EmailOfUser: "mostafa@gmail.com",
});
```

More detail information in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512388/understanding-async-await-on-nodejs)

After the POST request is successful, It extract the data from the response and set it to the responseData state variable using setResponseData. This will trigger a re-render, updating the UI with the response data.

```js
setResponseData(response.data);
```

This code will work.

##### File Tree

[image]

`axios` version
Save as `index.js`

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Home = () => {
    const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState(null);

    const handlePostClick = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/CreateUser", {
                nameOfUser: "mostafa",
                ageOfUser: 22,
                phoneNumber: 201003443454,
                EmailOfUser: "mostafa@gmail.com",
            });
            setResponseData(response.data); // Update state with response data
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handlePostClick}>POST</button>
            {responseData && (
                <div>
                    <h2>Response Data:</h2>
                    <pre>{JSON.stringify(responseData, null, 2)}</pre>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

##### Express Server

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

let users = [];

app.post('/CreateUser', (req, res) => {
    const newUser = req.body;
    users.push(newUser);
    res.status(201).json(newUser);
});

const PORT = 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

##### Result

[image]