# web worker onerror event handler not triggered when rethrowing an error in the catch block of fetch api

Tags: fetch-api, web-worker, onerror

> **TL;DR;** *Is there an issue with rethrowing errors in promises (i.e. the fetch-api) and the webworker global onerror event handler ?*

I'm having a hard time bubbling up an error thrown by the fetch api in a web worker to the client  that started the web worker. I see an "***Uncaught (in promise) Error***" instead of the code in the webworkers ***self.onerror*** event handler.... 
When I throw an error in a synchronous function in that same web worker it does end up in the self.onerror event handler...

To explain in further detail, inside my webworker I'm having :

- an onerror event handler
- functions that call a webapi with the fetch api

I want to pass along certain errors encountered when calling the web api to my client... 
Thus I rethrow the error at the end of the fetch (in the catch block). 
This is how my current test looks like :

```
fetch('https://<server>/api/token?key=version', { method: 'GET', credentials: 'include'})
.then((response) => {
  throw new Error("Oh no - something went wrong");
  return response.json();
})
.then((data) => {
  /* do something with the data in normal flow */
})
.catch((error) => { 
  /* we want to pass along certain types of errors */
  throw(error); /* <---- this is the last error I see logged in F12 debug windows -->
})
```

However i **never** see the error reaching the onerror event handler, 
which looks like this (just some test output) :

```
self.onerror = function (event) {
    console.trace(event);
}
```

I see (using F12 debug) that an ***Uncaught (in promise) Error*** is logged at the line that the fetch api catch

Anything I'm overlooking ? Is there an issue with rethrowing errors and the global onerror event handler ?

Comment: o shoot.... 10 minutes after posting I finally found the answer... on StackOverflow.
this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992417 
The trick is to use setTimeout like this : ** setTimeout(function() { throw err; });  **

Comment: @Kaiido yes, it does. This was one of the two solutions

Comment: Yes I got it from your comments, stating that it was a dupe. So I did vote to close it as such, hoping it would help you in that demarche, but maybe I misunderstood that comment?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there are two ways that I can make sure a rethrown error in a promise (fetch-api is promise-based) get's bubbled up :

1 ) The trick mentioned in [How to bubble a web worker error in a promise via worker.onerror?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992417/how-to-bubble-a-web-worker-error-in-a-promise-via-worker-onerror)

-- > just wrap the throw (inside the fetch catch block) in a ***setTimeout*** :

```
 fetch
 .then()
 .catch((error) => { 
    setTimeout(function() { throw error; });
 })
```

2) The new way mentioned in [How to catch uncaught exception in Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001722/how-to-catch-uncaught-exception-in-promise)

-- > add an eventhandler for ***unhandledrejection*** to your webworker :

```
self.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function (event) {
    // the event object has two special properties:
    // event.promise - the promise that generated the error
    // event.reason  - the unhandled error object
    throw event.reason;
});
```