# Enzyme Test case failing when promise getting called internally in some other Utility method

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

When I do a shallow of a component, a `method_1()` get called in `componentDidMount()` which call an utility `method_2()` and finally it makes an call to `method_3()` which is a promise based request. 
It throws the below error when running `npm test`

Example:
**Loginn.spec.js:**

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Login />)
Error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

Flow of the code given below.

**Login.js:**

```
import { AuthService } from '../../react-auth';
    componentWillMount() {

        const config = {
            environment: 'qa',
            google: true
        }

        const updateLoginState = function (isBool, currentContext) {
                currentContext.updateState('authStatusCheck', isBool);
        }

         authService.init(config, this, updateLoginState)
    }
```

**Auth.js**

```
import UmsLib from './umsLib'
export default class AuthService{
   init(customOptions, loginContext, updateLoginState) {
          // some code.
           UmsLib.getStatus(customOptions, loginContext, updateLoginState);
   };
}
```

**ums.js**

```
import ums from ‘user-management’;
export class UmsLib{
   getStatus(config, loginContext, updateLoginState) {
        ums.init(this.configOptions)
               .then(user => {
                   console.log("promise-----------------")
                   if (user && ums.isReady) {
                       return updateLoginState(true, loginContext);
                   }
               })
               .catch(error => {
                   throw Error('Failed calling UMS Library', error);
               })
   }
}
```

I have added try/catch to throw all the possible error and also tried handling promise in the test case, but it seems I am doing wrong something somewhere. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: does enzyme shallow call componentWillMount?I think mount calls the lifecycle methods and not shallow?

Answer (score 2):

That's because of you `throw Error` inside `catch` function, which leads to unhandled promise rejection. That's exactly what you got in the console.

The matter is that `catch()` function returns `Promise`. [From MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch):

> The `Promise` returned by `catch()` is rejected if onRejected throws an error or returns a Promise which is itself rejected; otherwise, it is resolved.

[This SOF discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715367/why-can-i-not-throw-inside-a-promise-catch-handler) could also help to understand Promises chaining.