# get error from async function

Tags: javascript, error-handling, async-await

I want to show an error message if a error occours inside a script proved by an user. Example:

```
function one() { consolef.log("async"); }
async function two() { consolef.log("async"); }

one();
await two();
```

`window.onerror` fires only on `one()` but not on `two()`:

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
  var string = msg.toLowerCase();
  if (string.indexOf(substring) > -1) {
    alert('Script Error: See Browser Console for Detail');
  } else {
    console.log('Error showed in browser view');
    document.body.innerHTML += ` <div class = "alert alert-danger" >` + error + ` < /a>. </div>`;
  }

  return false;
};
```

Both errors are shown inside console but only `one()` in the browser.

Edit:
I was pointed to [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472439/catch-all-unhandled-javascript-promise-rejections) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001722/how-to-catch-uncaught-exception-in-promise). But both suggest to use `onrejectionhandled` and `onunhandledrejection` but both functions are not supported by Firefox. So I can't use these functions for all users.

Comment: You have to call function `two` with `await` keyword: `await two()`

Comment: javascript stops on error.

Comment: Use an `unhandledRejection` handler for promises

Comment: found a solution: an try and catch blocks works